# Manual ping is down, but shell script shows up

Tags: bash

1. Manual ping is down, but shell script shows up

**script3.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
cat host.txt |  while read h
do
    ping -c 1 "$h" | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f3 | tr -d '()'
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "$h is up"
    else
                echo "$h is down"
    fi
done
```

**Output**

```
user@APIC> ./script3.sh
10.1.1.1
Nexus01 is up
10.1.1.2
Nexus02 is up
user@APIC>
```

**Manual ping shows Nexus01 (10.1.1.1) is currently down**

```
user@APIC> ping Nexus01 -c 1
PING Nexus01 (10.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- Nexus01 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

user@APIC>

user@APIC> ping Nexus02 -c 1
PING Nexus02 (10.1.1.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from Nexus02 (10.1.1.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.171 ms

--- Nexus02 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.171/0.171/0.171/0.000 ms
user@APIC>
```

2. I was hoping to get the following output.

**Desired Output**

```
user@CiscoAPIC> ./script3.sh
Nexus01 - 10.1.1.1 is down
Nexus02 - 10.1.1.2 is up
user@CiscoAPIC>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### The Problem

*The exit code of pipeline is exit code of the **last** command in the pipeline.*

Consider:

```
ping -c 1 "$h" | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f3 | tr -d '()'
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
```

The exit code, `$?`, that the `if` statement sees is the exit code of `tr -d '()'`.  You want the exit code of `ping`.

We can demonstrate this with a simpler pipeline:

```
$ false | tr -d '()'; echo $?
0
$ true | tr -d '()'; echo $?
0
```

In both cases, the exit code above is success (`0`).  This is true even though `false` returns an exit code of `1`.

#### The Solution

If you are running bash (not `sh`), then the exit code you seek is available in the shell array `PIPESTATUS`.  For example:

```
$ false | tr -d '()'; declare -p PIPESTATUS
declare -a PIPESTATUS=([0]="1" [1]="0")
```

This shows that `false` exited with code `1`.  So, in your code, replace:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
```

with:

```
if [ "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" -eq 0 ]; then   # Bash only
```